# How to create a container image and download it from Azure Container Image

Tags: azure, image, powershell, containers, azure-container-instances

**I want to pull a Azure Container to my local system from the Azure Container Instance.**

[My Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXVuX.png)

my goal is to create an image from this container. I just don't know how :) I have now tried by running the arm script in Azure and creating the container. Now I have the container but don't know how to create an image of it and then download it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have made changes to the ACI container's filesystem which you want to persist in a new image, then, I'm afraid, without access to the underlying infrastructure hosting the container runtime, you shall not be able to perform a [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) or similar operation to build an image from a running container.

At the time of writing, since Azure Container Groups are Container-as-a-Service offering, Azure does not allow customers access to the underlying infrastructure that support them.

Instead you can write your own Dockerfile [[How-to](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)] with base image as `atmoz/sftp:latest` and adding additional layers for the desired modifications. You can refer to [atmoz/sftp on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/atmoz/sftp) for usage and guidelines.